# dynamically loading html title attribute

Tags: html, css, tags, title

Here is an excerpt from  my markup:

```
    <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_value', true); ?>" title="<?php the_tags(); ?>" alt="" class="thumb"></a>
```

I've put in the "title" attribute  `<?php the_tags(); ?>` which is a function from Wordpress.
When I check the markup in Firebug I see this:

```
li class="view view_2 view-first">
<a id="50" href="" class="thumb_link" onclick="update_default_proj_list(1, '', '_'); getProject(50);"><span class="selected"></span><img 

src="13370318682.jpg" title="Tags: &lt;a href=" http:="" whiteandgold.ro="" realty="" ?tag="house&quot;" rel="tag">house</a>, <a href="http://

whiteandgold.ro/realty/?tag=rent-3" rel="tag">rent</a>" alt="" class="thumb"&gt;
```

I've tried to hide that text with :

```
img.thumb[title] {text-indent:-9999px;}



a[rel~="tag"] { text-indent:-999px;}`
```

And it's not working, also you can see this [here](http://whiteandgold.ro/realty/) ( try to inspect a thumbnail)

Answer (score 0):

[the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) renders HTML, so you shouldn't put it inside the title attribute. Put it outside of any HTML attributes:

```
<div id="thepost">
  // stuff
  <?php the_tags(); ?>
</div>
```

If you still want to do this for some reason, you can make it work by using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_value', true); ?>" title="<?php htmlspecialchars(the_tags()); ?>" alt="" class="thumb"></a>
```

Or maybe you just want a comma-separated list of tags, in which case you can generate it using [get_the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) (which gives you an array of tags that you can do whatever you want with).

Comment: I've tried with htmlspecialchars and nothing is changed.  I need to put the tags in the title attribute becuase I have a search plugin that search only by the title attribute. Here is the search: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/KqCP5/3/) try to type " abc "

Comment: @CristoceaCostel - I suspect you want to build up a list of tags using `get_the_tags()`, since it doesn't have all the extra HTML junk. What did you change your code to and what does the output look like if you do the htmlspecialchars thing like I suggested?

Comment: I would have suggested `htmlentities` over `htmlspecialchars` -- more thorough. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php